# How to retrieve data with "@input set" in Typescript and Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm dealing with legacy code like this:

```
@Input() set ratio (ratio: { w: number, h: number }) { this._ratio = ratio || null; }
...
console.log(this._ratio.h);
```

My question is what should I put in the HTML to be able to read that var like that? I tried different things like

```
ratio="30,30"
ratio="{w:30,h:30}"
[ratio]="..."
```

etc. and I can't make it properly set that var.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need a `get` for ratio, otherwise, your second version is correct.

Here is an example

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ratio-display',
  template: '<span>{{ratio.w / ratio.h}}</span>'
})
export class RatioDisplay {
  ratio_ = {w: 1, h: 1};

  @Input() set ratio (ratio: {w: number, h: number}) { 
    if(ratio) {
      this.ratio_ = ratio; 
    }
  }
  get ratio () {
    return this.ratio_;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <ratio-display [ratio]="ratio"></ratio-display>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  ratio = {w: 30, h: 45};
}
```

A working Plnkr can be found here: https://plnkr.co/edit/4TuMEzfDB6hxyGbC6csQ?p=preview

Of course, the only reason you would need a setter in this case is if want to guard against being passed invalid components, if you just want a simple value to bind to, you can just use

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ratio-display',
  template: '<span>{{ratio.w / ratio.h}}</span>'
})
export class RatioDisplay {
  @Input() ratio = {w: 1, h: 1};
}
```

The object literal can also be directly passed from your template

```
<ratio-display [ratio]="{w: 30, h: 45}"></ratio-display>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/4TuMEzfDB6hxyGbC6csQ?p=preview

Comment: Mmm this code is part of a standalone component and it doesn't work like that. There's no getters and it's supposed to pick up the value directly from the HTML tag attribute. I know it works because it was already implemented in the past, but it was removed and there are no references in the code where it was used, just the component itself.

Comment: @LucianoFantuzzi Sorry, I misread earlier, I added another example, with no getters or setters, and that passes the value directly in markup. You have plenty of options.

Comment: Yeah! That was it! Thank you man! I read some some time ago about avoid "thanks" messages, but... here you are!

Comment: Glad I could help.